# Get and set local/web hyperlinks in Libre office Impress shape element using basic macro

Tags: libreoffice-basic, libreoffice-impress

Using macro written in basic trying to set and get hyperlink in a rectangular shape object. Currently can access selected shaped object, but unable to work with hyperlinks.
Final aim is to set web hyperlink and another slide hyperlink in two different shape objects.

```
oShape = ThisComponent.getCurrentSelection().getByIndex(0)  
oShape.getString()             ' able to get text from object
```

Comment: The main problem would be: there is no "selection" action during presentation mode. If you want to create a hyperlink on an object, and then read that hyperlink, [I had posted a solution before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77839099/unable-to-change-shape-color-using-macro-in-libreoffice-impress-presentation-mod/). The key is to set the interaction as hyperlink, and call this `getArgumentFromURL` in the code. Also, please be more clear on what you mean by "unable to work with hyperlinks".